# Symfony 2 - modify form value after submit

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-forms

How to change *firstName* value to empty string after submit, when form is invalid?

When I use `$form->get('firstName')->setData('');` it gives me

> **You cannot change the data of a submitted form.**

In SUBMIT same error, in PRE_SUBMIT the value isn't known yet.

Symfony 2.8.4. It's my simplified code:

```php
class TaskType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('firstName', TextType::class, [
                'required' => false,
                'attr' => ['maxlength' => 30,],
                'constraints' => [
                    new NotBlank(),
                    new Length(array('min' => 5, 'max' => 30)),
                ],
            ])
            ->add('Submit', SubmitType::class, ['label' => 'Submit first name'])
            ->addEventListener(FormEvents::POST_SUBMIT, function (FormEvent $event) {
                $formData = $event->getData();
                $form = $event->getForm();

                if (!$form->isValid()) {
                    //$form->get('firstName')->setData('');
                }
            });
    }
}

class DefaultController extends Controller
{
    public function newAction(Request $request)
    {
        $defaultData = ['firstName' => 'John'];

        $form = $this->createForm(TaskType::class, $defaultData);
        $form->handleRequest($request);

        if ($form->isSubmitted()) {
            if ($form->isValid()) {
                return $this->redirectToRoute('app_homepage');
            } else {
                //$form->get('firstName')->setData('');
            }
        }

        return $this->render('default/new.html.twig', array(
            'form' => $form->createView(),
        ));
    }
}
```

Comment: You would either need to invalidate it on the client side prior to submission to the server, but also ensure that you send back errors to the client on failed server side validation. Once it's been submitted to the server, you don't change anything. You just send validation errors back to the client.

Comment: Lets forget about client side validation. When I submit firstName => 'Joe' in view I get error message 'This value is too short. It should have 5 characters or more.' and value in input is 'Joe'. I want the same message but input value to be empty.

Comment: Depends on the framework you're using, of course, but the normal behavior of most server-side MVC frameworks is to return to the client displaying the same inputs, but showing the errors associated with those inputs.